# Using `sort` based on a regex-matching beginning

Tags: bash, sorting, text-processing, case-sensitive

I would like to sort an output similar to the following:

```
[drwxrwxrwx user   group      64]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/
[-rwxr-xr-x user   group    8.0K]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/file.txt
[drwxr-xr-x user   group     256]  /Users/user/Documents/
[---xrwxrwx resu   alpha    2.4K]  /amber/lights.bin
[-------rwx user   group    5926033185992]  /var/fix\ your\ permissions\ haha
```

Typically, I would use `sort`, however I want to sort this text in a specific way. Instead of using the `[` at the beginning, I want to sort the lines based on the first `/` character, and further down the line.

The result I want to achieve should look like this:

```
[drwxr-xr-x user   group     256]  /Users/user/Documents/
[drwxrwxrwx user   group      64]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/
[-rwxr-xr-x user   group    8.0K]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/file.txt
[---xrwxrwx resu   alpha    2.4K]  /amber/lights.bin
[-------rwx user   group    5926033185992]  /var/fix\ your\ permissions\ haha
```

As you can see, the lines are sorted this way: Symbols first, A-Z next, a-z last, all while ignoring the beginning `[...]`   portion. In other words, I want to sort these lines as if `[...]`   wasn't there.

I was thinking some regex magic could aid in making this more possible, something like `^\[.[rwx-]\{9\}.*\]`

As you might expect, simply running the output through `sort` gives us this:

```
[-------rwx user   group    5926033185992]  /var/fix\ your\ permissions\ haha
[---xrwxrwx resu   alpha    2.4K]  /amber/lights.bin
[-rwxr-xr-x user   group    8.0K]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/file.txt
[drwxr-xr-x user   group     256]  /Users/user/Documents/
[drwxrwxrwx user   group      64]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/
```

which is what I do not want.

Is what I am looking for in any way achievable? Thank you.

Note: even though `5926033185992` is very unlikely appear in my output, I added it to show that the lines won't always begin with the same length of characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to sort by a matched field, but a fixed field, it's always the 5th column. The problem is that you want a case sensitive sort, capitals first, while `sort` uses `LC_COLLATE`, which probably is `en_US.utf8` or similar (you can see with `locale`). You have to change it to use the ASCII order.

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort -k5 file
```

Output:

```
[drwxr-xr-x user   group     256]  /Users/user/Documents/
[drwxrwxrwx user   group      64]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/
[-rwxr-xr-x user   group    8.0K]  /Volumes/Sample\ Disk/file.txt
[---xrwxrwx user   alpha    2.4K]  /amber/lights.bin
[-------rwx user   group    5926033185992]  /var/fix\ your\ permissions\ haha
```

Comment: Oh, bravo. I had briefly though about splitting the two groups based on whether the first character was upper/lower and sorting both groups, but the `LC_COLLATE=C` will sort upper first by default. Well played.

Comment: Even though I would prefer a regex solution, this still works perfectly. Thank you very much for your answer, I was struggling on this one for quite a while.

Comment: If I decided on sorting the list case-insensitively (`/amber/lights`, `/Users`, etc.) how would I go about doing that? I'm still up in the air as to which I'm going to settle with. **EDIT:** Never mind, figured it out. I added it to the answer.

Comment: Ok, scratch that. My edit was rejected. -_-    Anyway, use the `-f` option in `sort` for case insensitivity.